# Flood Fill Algorithm in Iphone Apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, flood-fill

I want to implement flood fill algorithm in my iphone app.I have been searching from long days and i have seen all the stack overflow answer but nothing helped me.

Please can any one post some sample application code which is using flood fill.

Comment: did you figure out this issue??

Comment: https://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, Wikipedia has [a great article about the flood fill algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) You just need to implement the algorithm and the pixel test in objective-c.

Comment: I read that page before itself.I want some help to where to start and how to start that